# FileNotFoundException while using multiple folders for Thymeleaf 3 template resolver

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm seeking to resolve Thymelaf templates that reside in different folders.  For example, I'd like to place email templates in a folder called `WEB-INF/thymeleaf/email` and web templates one level above.

This works for the email templates, but requesting any templates under `WEB-INF/thymeleaf` results in a `FileNotFoundException`:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/email/WebFile.html]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)`

Here is what I tried:

```
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
      <set>
    <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" />
    <ref bean="webTemplateResolver" />
      </set>
    </property>
    <property name="additionalDialects">
      <set>
        <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
      </set>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="emailTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/email/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
    <property name="order" value="2" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="webTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    <property name="order" value="3" />
  </bean>
```

**Note**: I am using the new Thymeleaf 3.0.0.BETA01 to take advantage of the more lenient parsing capabilities.  My stack trace reflects the new library so I know that it is deployed correctly.  I am using the `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` based on the [migration guide](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html).

Even a workaround would be appreciated (other than placing all the files in one folder).

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I am having the exact same problem. I even tried to put the file in the same folder. Still get FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by not explicitly stating the email folder:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="webTemplateResolver"/>
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="webTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML"/>
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
    <property name="order" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

(I have also since upgraded Spring Security to version 4, though I don't believe this was related.)

My structure looks like:

```
WEB-INF
  --->thymeleaf
      page.html
          --->email
              emailTemplate.html
```

Comment: Thanks! My issue was incorrect use of ".html" in my code. Got it working by removing the extra ".html" and using getSuffix in the templateResolver