# Mvc Thymeleaf Spring Http 500

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I already read similar questions, but I don't found the solution. I've got some problem with Thymeleaf, becaouse this code with jsp it's work. But with Thymeleaf it can't find my view page.

This is a WebConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = " namePackage.controller;")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
 @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   /*
    * STEP 1 - Create SpringResourceTemplateResolver
    * */
   @Bean
   public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
      SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
      templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
      templateResolver.setPrefix("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/");
      templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
      return templateResolver;
   }

   /*
    * STEP 2 - Create SpringTemplateEngine
    * */
   @Bean
   public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
      SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
      templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
      return templateEngine;
   }

   /*
    * STEP 3 - Register ThymeleafViewResolver
    * */
   public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
      ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
      resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
      registry.viewResolver(resolver);
   }
}
```

This is a simple controller

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/")
 public class BenvenutoController {
    @GetMapping("/ciao")
 public String ciao(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("mex", "Hello");
   return "welcome";
    }
 }
```

This is html page(view called "welcome")

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
</head>
<body>
<div >
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <p th:text="${mex}"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method addAllAttributes(Collection<?>) in the type Model is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

So It can't find my view page, but the path it's correct.
I'm using Spring Tool Suite like a idee.

All stack trace error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/welcome.html]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: The `src` directory is not a valid runtime location. Try `templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");` and see also [FileNotFoundException while using multiple folders for Thymeleaf 3 template resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526300/filenotfoundexception-while-using-multiple-folders-for-thymeleaf-3-template-reso).

Comment: @andrewjames thank you. I solve the problem. Java can't find the file if I'm writting so: setPrefinx("/WEB-INF/**), but java find the file if I'm writting so: setPrefix("WEB-INF/**)

Comment: Good news. You can write that as a answer, for future visitors. You can accept your own answer, too.

Comment: @andrewjames You can accept your own answer in 2 days

Answer (score 1):

The correct runtime location is: templateResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
Uncorrect is; templateResolver.setPrefix("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/"); and: templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace this Bean at WebAppConfig Step1:

```
@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver () {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return internalResolver;
    }
```

Comment: i tried to insert this bean, but with thymeleaf it doesn't work. I had to use "ThymeleafViewResolver".  I have already found the solution. I had entered the wrong path in setPrefix("/path");